# For( key in object )

Tags: javascript

```
for(var key in object )
```

I just wonder of the browser compatibility of this construction.
I might check it but I don't have ie6 for example.So may be someone knows

Comment: According to [JavaScript Version Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4esdbwz%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) `for..in` is available in IE6.

Answer (score 1):

According to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) the for..in loop is supported in javascript 1.0 (ECMA-262). [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) page should give you more info about support. However, AFAIK, that should be supported by any browsers supporting javascript, including ie6

Answer (score 0):

For .. in is a javascript loop , and not browser related , if your browser supports javascript then it will work for sure .

read more about javascript objects here :

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: Javascript is part of an evolving standard (*ECMA*) - different versions are supported by different vendors through their life-cycles.  it is ENTIRELY browser related - this is a terrible answer.

Comment: i guess i have said if browser supports Javascript then it will work ! do you have a proof it will not ?

Comment: Splitting hairs, [IE4 apparently didn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4esdbwz%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), but with any still supported browser, you're quite right.